# Python how to center a multiline string (containing `\n`) for printing in the center of the console?

Tags: python, string, terminal, console, center

I want to center a multiline string (containing new line characters (`\n`)) before printing of the terminal/console.

Doing `columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns` gives me the width of the ouput console and `print(""" test string """.center(columns))` prints the string to the center.

The code below prints a representation of a box with coordinates of the points:

```py
import shutil
X1,Y1,X2,Y2 = 90, 120, 162, 161
def print_box():
    def foo(a,b):
        if a<b: return ((b-a)//2)+a
        else  : return ((a-b)//2)+b

    center_line = foo(X1,X2),foo(Y1,Y2)
    tc  = foo(X1,center_line[0]),foo(Y1,center_line[1])
    bc = foo(X2,center_line[0]),foo(Y2,center_line[1])
    
    string = f"""
           Main box 

     {(X1,Y1)}
     (x1,y1) ------------
     |                  |
     |     Top box      |  
     |    {   tc   }    |
     |                  |
     |------------------| {center_line}
     |                  |
     |    Bottom box    |  
     |    {   bc   }    |
     |                  |
     -------------(x2,y2)  
                {(X2,Y2)}
             """
    columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
    print(f"""columns {columns}""".center(columns)) # MULTI LINE STRING WITH NO NEW LINES
    print(f"""columns\n {columns}""".center(columns)) # MULTI LINE STRING WITH NEW LINES
    
    print(string.center(columns)) # MULTI LINE STRING WITH NEW LINES
print_box()
```

running it outputs:

```
                                               columns 104                                               
                                              columns
 104

           Main box

     (90, 120)
     (x1,y1) ------------
     |                  |
     |     Top box      |
     |    (108, 130)    |
     |                  |
     |------------------| (126, 140)
     |                  |
     |    Bottom box    |
     |    (144, 150)    |
     |                  |
     -------------(x2,y2)
                (162, 161)
```

I want it to output:

```
                                                columns 104                                               
                                                columns 
                                                104

                                                       Main box

                                                 (90, 120)
                                                 (x1,y1) ------------
                                                 |                  |
                                                 |     Top box      |
                                                 |    (108, 130)    |
                                                 |                  |
                                                 |------------------| (126, 140)
                                                 |                  |
                                                 |    Bottom box    |
                                                 |    (144, 150)    |
                                                 |                  |
                                                 -------------(x2,y2)
                                                            (162, 161)
```

Comment: Did you try passing a larger number of columns as argument to `string.center`?

Comment: This can’t be the code which produces this output, as the code says `print("coums")`, but the output says `columns`. Please double check and create a [mre].

Comment: sorry typo i will correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, str.center doesn't work with multiline strings as you might want.

You could try

```
> "\n".join(line.center(columns)  for line in string.split("\n"))
```

Which splits `string` into each line and then performs a separate `str.center` on each line